# Find IDs where another column has at least two distinct values

Tags: sql

I have this:

```
SELECT DocumentID
FROM
(
SELECT DocumentID, Extension FROM Pages
GROUP BY DocumentID, Extension HAVING ( Count(1) > 2 )
) MultiplePages
GROUP BY MultiplePages.DocumentID Having ( Count(1) > 1 )
```

I am looking for a result set of Documents that have multiple pages where the pages do not share a distinct extension.  This query works but I was wondering if there was a better way.

Also, I am new to Stack Overflow and I am open to suggestions on creating better titles, descriptions, or how I might have searched for this question.
Thanks.

Comment: paraphrasing... you want DocumentIDs with distinct extensions, but only where the distinct extensions are used more than once per DocumentID

Comment: This is still confusing. Example data and output would make things much more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT DocumentID
FROM Pages
GROUP BY DocumentID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT(Extension)) > 1
```

or

```
SELECT DocumentID
FROM Pages
GROUP BY DocumentID
HAVING MIN(Extension) <> MAX(Extension)
```

Comment: This is great.  The second is not as easy to read but still easily understood.  I'm not a sql guru but the execution plan for both shows 
a 80 / 20 cost respectively.